# Can't paste images and text at once from Microsoft Word into TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, base64

I'm using the TinyMCE to copy and paste content from Microsoft Word and other Microsoft tools such as outlook.The following code is working, however, it requires the images been copied independently in order to be formatted to base64 properly and then can be displayed into the Tinymce text area. So the problem with that, is basically if I select text and images at once from Microsoft Word the URL of an image is not a base64 string if not a local filepath. I am wondering if there is a way to identify the src image before pasting and maybe read the image from my local machine and convert it in base64 string. I tried with some examples using canvas and filereader but i got browser exception (access permission).

```
 tinyMCE.init({
            // editor_selector: "mceEditor",
            selector: "textarea.mceEditor",
            theme: "modern",
            mode: "textareas",
            height: "180",
            plugins: "paste image textcolor",
            menubar: "edit",
            toolbar: "paste",
            toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
            toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | code',
            paste_data_images: true,
            paste_enable_default_filters: false,
            paste_retain_style_properties: "font-size,color",
            theme_advanced_buttons3_add: "pastetext,pasteword,selectall",
            paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
            paste_strip_class_attributes: "none",
            paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: false,
            paste_word_valid_elements: "b,strong,i,em,h1,h2,p,ol,ul,li,a,img",
            paste_webkit_styles: "color font-size",
            paste_preprocess: function (pl, o) {
                // Content string containing the HTML from the clipboard
                //alert(o.content);
                o.content = o.content;
                alert(o.content);
            },
            paste_postprocess: function (pl, o) {
                // Content DOM node containing the DOM structure of the clipboard
                //alert(o.node.innerHTML);
                o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find a solution?